# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named github, on raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I was curious if anyone knew a workaround, or what I am doing wrong when trying to install the import GitHub on Raspberry Pi. On my main machine all I needed to do was `import github`, and then it would install with either pip, or through the IDE. But when I try to install it on the pi, it gives me this error, or if I try to install it via pip with the following: `python -m pip install github` or `pip install github` it gives me `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement GitHub (from versions:none)`.

I have made sure that I am using python 3 and have also made sure that I have root access, but still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `github` is an old package with only version 0.0.0 on PyPI. You are surely looking for one of the countless other github packages.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the module that provides an import named `github` is in fact [PyGithub](https://pypi.org/project/PyGithub/).